# Find all the function that satisfy $f(x+y)+1=f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let function $f:R\setminus 0\to R$ such

(1):
$$\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right),\forall x\neq 0$$
(2): for any $x,y$ such
$$f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)+1,\forall x+y\neq 0$$

Find $f$

Let $P(x,y)$ be the assertion $f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)+1$,
$Q(x)$ be the assertion $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$.
Subtracting $Q(-1)\Longrightarrow f(-1)=0$
$$P(1,0)\Longrightarrow f(0)=1$$
Subtracting $P(-1,-1)\Longrightarrow f(-2)=-1$
Subtracting $P(-1,-2)\Longrightarrow f(-3)=-2$.

But I can't prove $f(x)=x+1$

Comment: If you suspect that $f(x)=x+1$, it could be worthwhile to let $f(x)=x+1+h(x)$, and then derive the functional equations that $h$ satisfies, and solve those.

Comment: OP doesn't have differentiability hypothesis

Comment: @sinbadh I think the comment meant "derive" as in "deduce," not "take a derivative."

Comment: @kccu Thanks for clarifying - yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: I don't exactly understand the question. I mean, showing that the f you found (f(x)=x+1) satisfies (1) and (2) by just inserting it into (1) and (2) seems rather trivial...is your question how to show uniqueness of your solution?

Comment: @Engineertryingmath Yes, the question is to show that $f(x)$ *must* be $x+1$, not that $x+1$ is a solution.

Comment: For (1) if F is a solution then so is kF for any constant k, and if F,G are solutions then so is F+G. Since 1+x is a solution, the Q is whether there is a solution not equal to k(1+x) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting $g(x)=f(x)-1$ and aditionaly $g(0)=0$, (2) is equivalent to $g(x)+g(y)=g(x+y)$. From this we can deduce, among other things, $g(2x)=2g(x)$ and $g(\frac{x}{2})\frac{g(x)}{2}$.

Now (1) is saying that for $x\neq 0$ $\frac{g(x)}{x}+\frac{1}{x}=g(\frac{1}{x})+1$. By replacing $x$ with $2x$ we get $\frac{g(2x)}{2x}+\frac{1}{2x}=g(\frac{1}{2x})+1$, so we have, by above, $\frac{g(x)}{x}+\frac{1}{2x}=\frac{g(\frac{1}{x})}{2}+1$. Multiplying the latter equation by $2$ and subtracting the first one gives $\frac{g(x)}{x}=1,g(x)=x$.

Thanks Hagen for pointing out a (minor) flaw in earlier argument.

Comment: $g(-x)=g(x)$ is not as immediate as it seems as $g(x)+g(y)=g(x+y)$ follows from $(2)$ only when $x+y\ne 0$.

Comment: Hm, that's true. I have to think about a fix.

Comment: The fix should be easy by taking a detour: If $x\ne 0$ then  $g(2x)=g(x)+g(x)$ and $g(3x)=g(2x)+g(x)$ and $g(-x)+g(2x)=g(x)$.

Comment: @Wojown .Must be an error in solution to (1) because f(x)=2+2 x is also a solution.

Comment: @user254665 (1) and (2) are the same problem. It's just two conditions for a single function.